# Firefox substitute wrong fallback font with normal weight

Tags: firefox, fontconfig

Why this strange behavior is happening and how to fix it?

Details:

I have configured fallback Glagolitic font in fonts.conf:

```
<alias>
    <family>sans-serif</family>
        <prefer>
            ...
            <family>Noto Sans Glagolitic</family>
            ...
        </prefer>
    </family>
</alias>
```

And this works as expected everywhere:

[image: Everything is fine]

Except the firefox, which render chars in FreeSans for some reason.
BUT if I set a font-weight to bold it's choose the right font:

[image]

This is make no sense because 'Noto Sans Glagolitic' is not a bold font but a regular one:

```
$ fc-cat | grep Glagol
"NotoSansGlagolitic-Regular.ttf" 0 "Noto Sans Glagolitic:
familylang=en:style=Regular:stylelang=en:fullname=Noto Sans Glagolitic:
fullnamelang=en:slant=0:weight=80:width=100:...
```

It doesn't even have bold version! (It had tried to autobold it, but I have disabled this)